# How to open and modify these files?

Tags: windows

I've been pointed here from a question I've posted on superuser:
https://superuser.com/questions/848108/open-img-file-to-mod-a-software/848844#848844

Basically I'm trying to modify the background of a window of a software, because the only ones available are too bright and hurt my eyes if I stare the monitor for more than 10min!

I've found these files in a subfolder of the program but they are saved with an extension .img, however this is not the real extension actually.

You can find the files here: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxENJdqZ02Q0LUNRZVZGVEpxZXc&usp=sharing

And here the answer that pointed me here: https://superuser.com/a/848844/153946

Can you help me to open these files and modify them in order to get a black background?

Answer (score 3):

These files are archives, as the superuser post suggested.

Each file has a 4 byte header which has the value "20SR", a 4 byte value that holds the number of files in the archive, then an array of 52 byte filename/length info, and the file data. Each file consists of a 4 byte value that repeats the size, then a deflated byte stream of the original file data.

The following C program rips these file(s) apart:

*WARNING: Do not use as an example for good programming style. Error checking is minimal.*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <zlib.h>

struct filedesc {
        char filename[40];
        int origsize, compressedsize, filepos;
};

char *emalloc(int n);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        FILE *fp, *out;
        char header[4], *inbuf, *outbuf;
        char basename[256];
        int i, j;
        int nfiles;
        struct filedesc filedesc;
        z_stream stream;

        if (sizeof(nfiles)!=4) {
                fprintf(fp, "int size not 32 bit -> aborting\n");
                exit(1);
        }
        for (i=1; i<argc; i++) {
                if ((fp=fopen(argv[i], "rb"))==NULL) {
                        perror(argv[i]);
                        continue;
                }
                fread(header, 4, 1, fp);
                if (memcmp(header, "20SR", 4)) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Wrong File Format\n", argv[i]);
                        fclose(fp);
                        continue;
                }
                printf("===== %s ======\n", argv[i]);
                fread(&nfiles, sizeof nfiles, 1, fp);
                for (j=0; j<nfiles; j++) {
                        fseek(fp, 8+(long)j*sizeof filedesc, 0);
                        fread(&filedesc, sizeof filedesc, 1, fp);
                        printf("%2d: %-40s %08x %08x %08x\n", j,
                                filedesc.filename, filedesc.origsize, filedesc.compressedsize, filedesc.filepos);
                        fseek(fp, (long)filedesc.filepos+4, 0);
                        strcpy(basename, argv[i]);
                        if ((outbuf=strchr(basename, '.'))==NULL) {
                                strcat(basename, ".d");
                                outbuf=basename+strlen(basename);
                        } else {
                                *outbuf='\0';
                        }
                        mkdir(basename, 0777);
                        strcat(basename, "/");
                        strcat(basename, filedesc.filename);

                        if ((out=fopen(basename, "wb"))==NULL) {
                                perror(basename);
                        } else {
                                inbuf=malloc(filedesc.compressedsize-4);
                                outbuf=malloc(filedesc.origsize);
                                fread(inbuf, filedesc.compressedsize-4, 1, fp);
                                stream.zalloc=Z_NULL;
                                stream.zfree=Z_NULL;
                                stream.opaque=Z_NULL;
                                stream.avail_in=filedesc.compressedsize;
                                stream.next_in=inbuf;
                                stream.avail_out=filedesc.origsize;
                                stream.next_out=outbuf;
                                inflateInit(&stream);
                                inflate(&stream, Z_FINISH);
                                inflateEnd(&stream);

                                fwrite(outbuf, filedesc.origsize, 1, out);
                                fclose(out);
                                free(inbuf);
                                free(outbuf);
                        }
                }
                fclose(fp);
        }
}

char *emalloc(int n) {
        char *t;
        if ((t=malloc(n))==NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "no space\n");
                exit(1);
        }
        return t;
}
```

I may or may not have the time to create a program to compress a bunch of files over the weekend. Btw, the images in the table*.img files seem to be buttons or something similar, i guess the background itself is defined in one of the css files in layout.img.